# How to prevent a media attribute from matching anything

Tags: javascript, css

I have a `<picture>` tag with `<source srcset="..." media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">` inside.

In my Javascript code, I need to switch the media attribute between the following 3 states:

1. Only matching when the OS is in dark mode
2. Always matching
3. Never matching

I am currently achieving this by setting `media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"`, `media=""` and `media="match_nothing"` for states 1, 2 and 3 respectively. I tried it, and it seemed to achieve the exact result I was looking for.

Other than by deleting the entire source element, is there a documented way of achieving this result, without using the improvised `"match_nothing"` attribute value?

Comment: interesting, `<source src=""` is apparently not allowed if the parent element is `<picture>`

Comment: perhaps `media="not(all)"` ???

Comment: @JaromandaX aha, thanks, `not(all)` works! Also, I meant to type `srcset=` instead of `src=` in the question